# YAML development dependencies required for YAML configuration format handling

Tags: cmake, fluent

I follow the fluent-bit https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/installation/sources/build-and-install documentation. But when cmake, It show the log below.I know I can just disable the yaml feature. If I do not disable, what should I do to add the "YAML development dependencies"?

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:678 (message):
  YAML development dependencies required for YAML configuration format
  handling.

  This is a build time dependency, you can either install the dependencies or
  disable the feature setting the CMake option -DFLB_CONFIG_YAML=Off .
```

Comment: According to the [code](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L671) which is tried to compile, it requires the header `yaml.h`. That header is provided by libyaml.

Comment: I added apt install libyaml-dev worked for me on debian bullseye (and in the fluent-bit container)

Answer (score 1):

You should add the libyaml-dev (for debian based distros) or libyaml-devl (centos/fedora).

```bash
# centos family:
yum install -y libyaml-devel

# debian family:
apt-get install -y libyaml-dev
```